# React Native User Authentication via Identity Server 4

Tags: android, react-native, authentication, identityserver4

I am working on a React Native application that needs to authenticate the user via Identity Server 4. The flow:

1. User opens Android app (or iOS but not there yet)
2. User is redirected to authorization server (Identity Server)
3. User authenticates
4. User is redirected back to Native app with scheme (com.myapp.auth:/oauthredirect)

An issue is occurring for me during the redirect. After entering the credentials on the auth server and successfully logging in, Identity Server is redirecting the user back to the login page instead of the Native app.

I thought at first that the Identity Server is checking for the existence of a cookie before redirecting but I can't find source code to support that theory. In fact, my Identity Server is using javascript to change the window location in order to redirect (no cookies). Below is the code responsible for redirecting after user enters credentials. This code was written by Identity Server authors (QuickStart package).

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Handle postback from username/password login
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)
        {
            // check if we are in the context of an authorization request
            var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);

            // the user clicked the "cancel" button
            if (button != "login")
            {
                if (context != null)
                {
                    // if the user cancels, send a result back into IdentityServer as if they 
                    // denied the consent (even if this client does not require consent).
                    // this will send back an access denied OIDC error response to the client.
                    await _interaction.DenyAuthorizationAsync(context, AuthorizationError.AccessDenied);

                    // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
                    if (context.IsNativeClient())
                    {
                        // The client is native, so this change in how to
                        // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                        return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", model.ReturnUrl);
                    }

                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    // since we don't have a valid context, then we just go back to the home page
                    return Redirect("~/");
                }
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // validate username/password against in-memory store
                var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
                if (user != null && (await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, true)) ==
                    SignInResult.Success)
                {
                    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName,
                        clientId: context?.Client.ClientId));

                    // only set explicit expiration here if user chooses "remember me". 
                    // otherwise we rely upon expiration configured in cookie middleware.
                    AuthenticationProperties props = null;
                    if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
                    {
                        props = new AuthenticationProperties
                        {
                            IsPersistent = true,
                            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                        };
                    }

                    // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
                    var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.Id)
                    {
                        DisplayName = user.UserName
                    };

                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, props);

                    if (context != null)
                    {
                        if (context.IsNativeClient())
                        {
                            // The client is native, so this change in how to
                            // return the response is for better UX for the end user.


                            // !!!! This is where the user is redirected to app
                            return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", model.ReturnUrl);
                        }

                        // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }

                    // request for a local page
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect("~/");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
                        throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
                    }
                }

                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(model.Username, "invalid credentials",
                    clientId: context?.Client.ClientId));
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
            }

            // something went wrong, show form with error
            var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model);
            return View(vm);
        }
```

This is 'Controller::LoadingPage' extension:

```
public static IActionResult LoadingPage(this Controller controller, string viewName, string redirectUri)
        {
            controller.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            controller.HttpContext.Response.Headers["Location"] = "";

            return controller.View(viewName, new RedirectViewModel {RedirectUrl = redirectUri});
        }
```

Here is the Redirect view:

```
@model RedirectViewModel

<div class="redirect-page">
    <div class="lead">
        <h1>You are now being returned to the application</h1>
        <p>Once complete, you may close this tab.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=@Model.RedirectUrl" data-url="@Model.RedirectUrl">
<script src="~/js/signin-redirect.js"></script>
```

Here is 'signin-redirect.js':

```
window.location.href = document.querySelector("meta[http-equiv=refresh]").getAttribute("data-url");
```

Here is Native code to perform auth process. I'm using react-native-app-auth to handle authentication.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
// @ts-ignore
import { authorize, prefetchConfiguration } from 'react-native-app-auth';
import Store from 'core/store';
import Api from 'core/Api';
import { AUTH_PROVIDER } from 'core/constants';

const ISSUER = 'https://identity.mydomain.com';

const config = {
    // issuer: ISSUER,
    clientId: 'my-native-app',
    redirectUrl: 'com.myapp.auth:/oauthredirect',
    scopes: 'openid profile api'.split(' '),
    serviceConfiguration: {
        authorizationEndpoint: `${ISSUER}/connect/authorize`,
        tokenEndpoint: `${ISSUER}/connect/token`,
        revocationEndpoint: `${ISSUER}/connect/revocation`,
    },
    usePKCE: true,
};

type Props = {};
class Session extends React.Component<Props> {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.init();
    }

    private async init() {
        this.renew();
    }

    private renew() {
        authorize(config)
            .then(result => {
                console.log('auth result', result);
                Store.session = result;
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => this.renew()}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
                <Text>{!!Store.session ? Store.session.accessToken : 'not available'}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Session;
```

How do I properly redirect the user back to the app?

**UPDATE**:
I believe the redirect is working correctly now, however, a network error is occurring. Here is the entire auth server log for the request:

```
[15:22:09 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.

[15:22:09 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint

[15:22:09 Information] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
Start authorize request

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
User in authorize request: b0007bd7-51fb-4fe8-9f6d-0381ae503f23

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
Start authorize request protocol validation

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ClientStore
my-native-client found in database: True

[15:22:09 Verbose] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore
Calling into client configuration validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultClientConfigurationValidator

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore
client configuration validation for client my-native-client succeeded.

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
Checking for PKCE parameters

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
Found ["profile", "openid"] identity scopes in database

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
Found ["my-webapi"] API resources in database

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore
Found ["api"] scopes in database

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator

[15:22:09 Verbose] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
Authorize request protocol validation successful

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{"ClientId": "my-native-client", "ClientName": "My Native User Interface", "RedirectUri": "com.myapp.auth:/oauthredirect", "AllowedRedirectUris": ["com.eqdesk.auth:/loginredir
ect", "com.myapp.auth:/silentrenew"], "SubjectId": "b0007bd7-51fb-4fe8-9f6d-0381ae503f23", "ResponseType": "code", "ResponseMode": "query", "GrantType": "authorization_code", "
RequestedScopes": "openid profile api", "State": "MIqKRXmE_MNLKX2raQ5DjQ", "UiLocales": null, "Nonce": "R1XHSeBYuvnakVGMeVzruA", "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null, "
DisplayMode": null, "PromptMode": "", "MaxAge": null, "LoginHint": null, "SessionId": "5C19FD17860D7DD7538F9E9267DFC121", "Raw": {"redirect_uri": "com.eqdesk.auth:/loginredirect
", "client_id": "my-native-client", "response_type": "code", "state": "MIqKRXmE_MNLKX2raQ5DjQ", "nonce": "R1XHSeBYuvnakVGMeVzruA", "scope": "openid profile api", "code_challenge":
"e6hobS24s9avKdEzBw_Q4I45HvM_q6Ml99NbpFbKiCg", "code_challenge_method": "S256"}, "$type": "AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"}

[15:22:09 Verbose] IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator
ProcessInteractionAsync

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultConsentService
Client is configured to not require consent, no consent is required

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator
Creating Authorization Code Flow response.

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore
5R16ABKoTQe/xhjFJLAUhK9DwzxkzCXIJFH3ayArfaI= not found in database

[15:22:09 Verbose] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
Code issued for my-native-client / b0007bd7-51fb-4fe8-9f6d-0381ae503f23: 6F7F7F1A69D192D46B711DDF2168933B7069AA0D84E213811867BA28A4A73056

[15:22:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
Authorize endpoint response
{"SubjectId": "b0007bd7-51fb-4fe8-9f6d-0381ae503f23", "ClientId": "my-native-client", "RedirectUri": "com.myapp.auth:/oauthredirect", "State": "MIqKRXmE_MNLKX2raQ5DjQ", "Scope": "
openid profile api", "Error": null, "ErrorDescription": null, "$type": "AuthorizeResponseLog"}

[15:22:09 Verbose] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
End authorize request. result type: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.AuthorizeResult

[15:22:09 Verbose] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.AuthorizeResult
```

And, here is the error as observed in React Native:

```
{"code": "token_exchange_failed", "message": "Network error", "nativeStackAndroid": [{"class": "net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService$TokenRequestTask", "file": "AuthorizationService.java", "lineNumber": 636, "methodName": "doInBackground"}, {"class": "net.openid.appauth.AuthorizationService$TokenRequestTask", "file": "AuthorizationService.java", "lineNumber": 564, "methodName": "doInBackground"}, {"class": "android.os.AsyncTask$3", "file": "AsyncTask.java", "lineNumber": 378, "methodName": "call"}, {"class": "java.util.concurrent.FutureTask", "file": "FutureTask.java", "lineNumber": 266, "methodName": "run"}, {"class": "android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1", "file": "AsyncTask.java", "lineNumber": 289, "methodName": "run"}, {"class": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor", "file": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java", "lineNumber": 1167, "methodName": "runWorker"}, {"class": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker", "file": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java", "lineNumber": 641, "methodName": "run"}, {"class": "java.lang.Thread", "file": "Thread.java", "lineNumber": 919, "methodName": "run"}], "userInfo": null} [Error]
```

Comment: have you checked the logs from identityserver during redirecting back to login page? in normal flow the login page first redirects back to authorization endpoint, and only from there, having the cookie in place (created by `await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, props);` from your listing), back to requesting app.

Comment: Most likely you go through the bottom `return View(vm);`, but there must be an error presented, strange that it does not

Comment: Thanks @d_f. I will check logs again. Is there anything special I need to do in order to support cookies in a React Native app?

Comment: Actually @d_f the controller logic returns here (within ModelState.IsValid):
```if (context.IsNativeClient())
                        {                            return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", model.ReturnUrl);
                        }```

Comment: then again, try to check the logs. normally the url, the js on "Redirect" page is taking as an argument, must look like: _/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=<your-client-id>&redirect_uri=<your-redirect-url>&response_type=code&scope=openid%20<your-additional-scopes>&response_mode=form_post&nonce=<nonce>_ so the call goes through the _authorize/callback_ where tries to find the session cookie

Comment: Indeed the user is first redirected to the authorize endpoint. I posted the response in the question above.

Comment: that is from `AuthorizeEndpoint` (invoked **before** posting the login form) while we are now more interested in the `AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint`, starting from [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/8b027820d9b8c20adcd8d6b495444d08cced45ca/src/IdentityServer4/src/Endpoints/AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint.cs#L50) log

Comment: Update: I have posted the entire auth server log.